# Why is there an extra space in console output of CLion?

Tags: c, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

There is a extra space (indentation) in the output of my code. The output should be :

```
Enter your number: 
Enter your number: 
Enter your number:
```

but that is not the case this, is the CLion 2019.1.2 output:

```
Enter your number:
 Enter your number:
 Enter your number:
```

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main (void){
    int x =0;

    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is clearly a tool bug. There should clearly be no indention or extra spaces produced by the code posted.

Comment: I also use the same version (on Windows) and can't replicate your output with the code you show. What OS are you on?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using Windows 10 x64

Comment: I copy-pasted the code you show and ran it in the same environment, and [I don't get the same output as you](https://i.imgur.com/U98WaUs.png).

Comment: @Lundin It is not necessarily a tool bug. It might be an effect of stream buffering.

Comment: Try calling `fflush(stdout);` between the `printf` calls and the following `scanf` calls.

Comment: @IanAbbott Stream buffering wouldn't change what is the output, only when it gets there.

Comment: @Lundin: Exactly. There are just as many spaces in the output as there should be, but they have been deferred.

Comment: There are no extra spaces in the output. In fact, the final space has not yet been output yet in your screenshot.

Comment: Do you have to use scanf? I try to avoid scanf and prefer to take my inputs as strings use fgets then convert the data to the required datatype after. Can you try using fgets instead and see if you produce the same result?

Comment: There are some problems with displaying the output in case of MinGW.
Maybe this link will help you.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006383859-CLion-moving-space-into-new-line

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds:

1. disabling PTY (`Help | Find Action` > type "Registry" > open Registry > find and disable the **run.processes.with.pty** option).
2. enabling the "Run in external console" option in your run/debug configuration (`Run | Edit Configurations...`).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. I'm unsure of any limitations but a workaround that satisfied me was to go to Run (at the top) > Edit Configurations.. > Check "Emulate terminal in the output console".

Answer (score -3):

each of your printf statements has a space at the end after the ':' and before the ", this causes the next printf statement to have a space before it is printed to the console

change:

```
printf("Enter your number: ");
```

to:

```
printf("Enter your number:");
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the correct answer.  The OP was asking about spaces at the BEGINNING of his line, not at the end.